# c# File1's text keeps replacing file2's when I run it

Tags: c#

All I need is for file1 and file2 to show the text inside the file. File1 is working great! File2 not so much. I believe there is something wrong with how I wrote file2 being read. Because I made a class so that I can make file2's text go to another file called outputfile2, and even that isn't working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RandomName
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string winDir = 
"C:/Users/RandomPerson/Desktop/RandomName/bin/Debug/";

        string fileName = "file1.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(winDir + fileName);

        string outputFileName = "upperfile" + fileName;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileName);

        int n = 0;
        string st = "";
        string upperString = "";
        int n2 = 0;
        string st2 = "";
        string upperString2 = "";



        string fileName2 = "file2.txt";

        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(winDir + fileName2);
        string outputFileName2 = "output" + fileName2;
        StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter(outputFileName2);

        do
        {
            ++n;
            st = reader.ReadLine();  // read one line from disk file
            Console.WriteLine("Line #" + n + ": " + st);  // write to the console
            writer.WriteLine(st);  // write line to disk file instead, using WriteLine() method
            upperString = upperString + "\n" + st;  // append each line to the big string

        }
        while (!reader.EndOfStream);

        do
        {
            ++n2;
            st2 = reader2.ReadLine();  // read one line from disk file
            Console.WriteLine("Line #" + n2 + ": " + st2);  // write to the 
console
            writer2.WriteLine(st2);  // write line to disk file instead, 
using WriteLine() method
            upperString2 = upperString2 + "\n" + st2;  // append each line 
to the big string
        }
        while (!reader2.EndOfStream);
        reader.Close();  
        writer.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("\nHere is the entire file in a string:");
        Console.WriteLine(upperString);
        Console.WriteLine(upperString2);

        UpperString b = new UpperString(upperString);
        UpperString2 c = new UpperString2(upperString2);

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe string in reverse case: ");
        b.showReverseCase();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        c.readingFile2();
        c.toNewFile2();

    }

}
}
```

"b." is for another class that I have. I copied the code from that class into the "c." one, changing names of strings and such. And that didn't work. Which is why I think something is wrong somewhere in the main.

Here is the class

```
class UpperString2
{
    private string upperString2;

    public UpperString2() { }

    public UpperString2(string c) { upperString2 = c; }


    public void readingFile2()
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:/Users/SomeName/Desktop/FolderName/bin/Debug/file2.txt");            

        System.Console.WriteLine("\nAnother Poem  \n");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

    }

    public void toNewFile2()
    {
        using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("outputfile2.txt"))
        {
            string newText = (upperString2.ToUpper()).ToString();

            writetext.WriteLine(newText);
        }

    }
```

I am a bit new to SteamReader and SteamWriter, which is why I think I went wrong somehow with that. I'm not sure what though. Thank you anyone who can help me have the text in file2 show up without it being overwritten by file1's text!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "outputfile2" was already opened by `reader2` in `Main()`.

```
string fileName2 = "file2.txt";
StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(winDir + fileName2);
string outputFileName2 = "output" + fileName2; //<--outputfile2.txt
StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter(outputFileName2)
```

Then it raises an exception when you try to open the same file for writting in `toNewFile2()`:

```
public void toNewFile2()
{
    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("outputfile2.txt"))
    {
        string newText = (upperString2.ToUpper()).ToString();

        writetext.WriteLine(newText);
    }
}
```

This happens because the object `writer2` is still alive and locking the file in `Main()` and there's no `using` statement for disposing the object when no longer needed.

Since you have moved the code to a class, call that class instead.